# SpringBoot DataSource configuration

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to use the `application.properties` file to configure the datasource Spring Boot will have to use.

I've put the following properties inside :

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.user=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
```

The `application.properties` file is well used by other systems. But I can't get it to work for the automatic datasource configuration.

I'm still getting this Exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database url for database type NONE.
```

The postgresql driver is included and loaded. And I can configure the datasource using a `Configuration` class, and the same parameters as above.

I've also added the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` to my `Application.class`.

Any clues?

Comment: Do you have one of the supported `DataSource` implementations on the classpath (e.g. Tomcat JDBC)?

Comment: Yes I have them. When I manually configure the datasource it works like a charm.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use `spring.datasource.url` to configure the JDBC URL rather than `spring.datasource.jdbcUrl`.

`spring.datasource.jdbcUrl` will work if the specific `DataSource` implementation that you're using has a `setJdbcUrl` method (HikariCP, for example) where as `spring.datasource.url` will work with any of the supported datasources.

Using `spring.datasource.url` also has the added benefit that you don't need to specify `spring.datasource.driverClassName` as it will be inferred from the url.