# (Spring properties) jdbc-url vs url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource, spring-jdbc

I programaticaly configured my `DataSource` and I'm encountering an error saying:

`dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required`.

I managed to make it work by just changing `spring.datasource.url` in my .properties file.

**Having errors:** `spring.datasource.url`

**No errors:** `spring.datasource.jdbc-url`

What I don't know is how does it make it work by just specifying `jdbc-url` instead of `url`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SpringBoot DataSource configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175460/springboot-datasource-configuration)

Comment: @SangamBelose OP has the opposite issue

Comment: Just found an excellent answer from **lapkritinis** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088847/after-spring-boot-2-0-migration-jdbcurl-is-required-with-driverclassname

Answer (score 0):

This is how the properties are defined in my project:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mySchema
spring.datasource.username=theUserName
spring.datasource.password=123456
```

Comment: My property is `spring.main-datasource.url` but that gives me the error `dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.` I managed to make it work by changing `url` to `jdbc-url`